# When executing more than one stored procedures manually in sql, does it run them sequentially?

Tags: sql

From top to bottom?

example:

```
exec storedprocedure1
exec storedprocedure2
exec storedprocedure3
```

If I hightlight all three and execute, does it run #1 first, then #2, #3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server and highlighting in SSMS then, Yes.

Answer (score 1):

The statements are executed in order.  One statement does not run until the preceding one is completed.  If one statement generates an error then (in general) the script will abort with an error (or go to an error handler at a higher level).

This is standard in scripting languages.  The alternative would be parallel execution, which would generally require a multi-threading interface.  This is possible in databases, because they are generally multi-threaded anyway.  However, it is not the default for SQL nor for any other scripting language (to my knowledge).